# Google Sheets formula that will Check two columns and if both are true, pull value from third column

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

## Google Sheets formula that will Check two columns and if both are true, pull value from third column.

I am trying to put together a system so my office can keep track of our budgets in real time.  I have linked a google form to a google sheet and trying to find a formula that will pull starting balances.  One page is where the google form dumps the information, and the second page is used to track the important information; starting balance, current balance, and date updated.  Right now, I'm stuck trying to get the second page to pull the starting balance.

On the page linked to the google form,
[Picture of Data Dump Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EJ5N.png)

I need to check to see if the Method of Debit (Column L) is "Budget Load" and also that What Account was Debited? (Column M) is "Supplies and Services".  If both of these are true, then it should pull the number from Amount of Debt (Column O) and put it in the second sheet.

[Picture of Data Deposit Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVLgn.png)

It should be deposited under Beginning Amount (Column N) next to Supplies and Services.  I have tried all sorts of combinations with no luck.

There will be multiple additions across multiple accounts so the function will need to search through multiple rows and be able to find the two matches.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried multiple combinations of VLOOKUP, AND, IF, IFS, etc.  Using the AND function, I thought I could get the formula to lookup or use if/s to compare the two columns and then return the third column, but no matter what I tried the AND function would return FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options to put into N2 of the "Data Deposit Sheet":

1. This option uses QUERY and ARRAYFORMULA to pull in the matching cells automatically, so you don't have to drag the formula down to the other rows:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY('Data Dump Sheet'!L2:O, "SELECT O WHERE L = 'Budget Load' AND M = 'Supplies and Services'")))

2. If you'd like to make edits on a row-by-row basis, then try this one in N2 and drag it down to the following rows:

> =IFERROR(INDEX('Data Dump Sheet'!$O$2:$O, SMALL(
> IF(('Data Dump Sheet'!$L$2:$L = "Budget Load") * ('Data Dump Sheet'!$M$2:$M = "Supplies and Services"),
> ROW('Data Dump Sheet'!O2:O) - ROW('Data Dump Sheet'!O2) + 1),
> ROW()-1)),
> "")